# Reduce Hair/Fur height on select faces or vertices in New Hair Geometry Node Blender 3.5?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have created Hair/Fur on a plane and which is working fine, but I want to reduce/remove fur on a few selected vertices on the plane.
[image: No Fur Faces]

How can i provide a vertex group value to hair trim height to specifically not have or have short hairs on those vertices (Value of Height can be taken from Vertex Weight) ?

[image: Vertex Group]

I am adding the Hair Trim Node Setup, It is not a custom setup and only used from presets available in Hair Geometry Node Asset Library.
[image: Hair Trim Nodes 1]
[image: Hair Trim Nodes 2]